# How to add more disk space to "/" folder centos

Tags: centos7, mount

By check

```
fdisk -l
```

I see (more than 900 GB)

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 959.7 GB, 959656755200 bytes, 1874329600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb599f429

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     8390655     4194304   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         8390656    12584959     2097152   82  Linux swap /         
 Solaris
/dev/sda3        12584960  1874329599   930872320   8e  Linux LVM
Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home: 912.7 GB, 912680550400 bytes, 1782579200 
sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

But when I mount it to /

```
mount /dev/mapper/vg00-home /
```

And check

```
df -h
```

There are only few of GB

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-home  3.9G  175M  3.7G   5% /
devtmpfs                16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   16G  8.7M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs                   16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr   4.8G 1023M  3.6G  23% /usr
none                    16G     0   16G   0% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg00-var   4.8G  228M  4.4G   5% /var
tmpfs                  3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

I have been googling for 2 days but I still do not know how to fix it. Please help me.

Comment: can you edit the question and share output of lvscan ? I think you need to do resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg00-home

Answer (score 2):

When you use LVM Increasing a disk is followed by a number of simple steps (correct arguments are left as an exercise for the reader)

- ✅ increase the partition (for instance with `fdisk`) - you seem to have already done that
- ✅ prepare the additional disk space for use by LVM (increase the physical volume) with `pvresize` - check with `pvdisplay`
- ✅  increase the logical volume with `lvextend` - check with `lvdisplay`
- increase the filesystem to make use of the increased LVM size , the command depends on the file system in use `resize2fs` is used for ext3/4 , confirm with `df`

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you help me a bit? I'm no good at server config.

Comment: Then either invest a bit in yourself and start to **learn** (every command comes with an online manual accessed with the `man` command, f.i. [`man resize2fs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) ) or hire someone who actually is a good sysadmin